# I want to extract a text from html page which has two types of class

Tags: python, html, xpath, extract

I want to extract shipping fees from the html page. But there are two types of html pages from which I need to extract the shipping fees.

for one page the Xpath is

```
//*[@class="flex flex-row justify-between f6 mid-gray pt2"]//div[2]/text()
```

for another page the Xpath is

```
//*[@class="mid-gray flex items-center"]//span/text()
```

Now I want to combine the above Xpaths as one so that if any one of the condition met it should extract the value
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIRWp.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PqU3.png)

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried so far. What is your problem, with your code? SO will not generate the code for you.

Comment: I need to extract shipping fees from HTML page, now there are two types of different pages from which I have to extract the shipping fees, I have shared the Xpath for both the pages. I need to combine them and make them as one so that I will be able to get the shipping fees in one column not in two columns.

Comment: for one page the Xpath is //[@class="flex flex-row justify-between f6 mid-gray pt2"]//div[2]/text() 
for another page the Xpath is //[@class="mid-gray flex items-center"]//span/text()
Now is it possible to combine the above code with some condition like of the first one is true then extract the text from first or from the second

Comment: where is your code ? where you stack?

Comment: @Tusher how can I share the code with you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
(//*[@class="flex flex-row justify-between f6 mid-gray pt2"]/div[@class="green"]
|
//*[@class="mid-gray flex items-center"]/span)[1]/text()
```

Explanation:

Surround the two with  `()` and the `|` combines the two, and `[1]` selects the first of those two